# Mapping a Json placeholder file to java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson, set, objectmapper

So I have the following JSON to represent a City object which I want to MAP to an object in JAVA.
This is used to filter out unwanted fields

```
   {
  "class": [
    {
      "id": "default",
      "type": [
        "riskType",
        "firstTime"
      ],
      "direction": [],
      "town": [
        "leader",
        {
          "streets": [
            "mainStreet"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To map it I am using a
`ojectMapper.readValue(inputStream, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Set<PayloadClass>>>() { });`

My payload class is as follows:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"town", "direction", "type"})
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PayloadClass {
private String id;
@NonNull private Set<String> type = Collections.emptySet();
@NonNull private Set<String> direction = Collections.emptySet();
@NonNull private Set<Town> town = Collections.emptySet();
```

And my town class is done as so to represent a a Town has a leader and streets

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Town{

@JsonProperty(value = "leader")
private String leader;

@JsonProperty(value = "streets")
private Set<String> streets = Collections.emptySet();
```

The issue is in the mapping, where it tries to map the leader and Set of streets within the one object.

I am then  getting the following error but not sure why:

```
U [main] ERROR - Cannot construct instance of ` 
com.Town` (although at least one Creator 
exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value 
('leader')
at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 16, column: 9] (through reference chain: 
java.util.HashMap["PayloadClass"]->java.util.HashSet[0]- 
com.PayloadClass["town"]->java.util.HashSet[1])
```

I am trying to keep the JSON in this format for upstream apps, hopefully I can resolve this issue in the mapping types.

So the new field I am trying to add, is the leader field within the Json. Without this field it performs without issue.

Comment: If town is an array of objects, you should write in json :
"town": [ {
        "leader",
        {
          "streets": [
            "mainStreet"
          ]
        }
      ]

Comment: @GweltazNiquel I tried it that was but it complains in the IDE about ||ERROR: ':' expected, got ',' || with the comma that follows "leader"

Comment: Do you have getters / setters on leader with public visibility ?
see : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json format is wrong. If town is an array of city objects with a leader and an array of street names, you should write in json :

```
{
  "town": [
    {
      "leader": "",
      "streets" :  [
        "mainStreet"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would but in the payload it appears as so: 
"PayloadClass(id=default, type=[riskType, firstTime], direction=[], town=[town(leader=, streets=[mainStreet])
where I don't want an "=" after leader and for it to pickup the payload in the same format "type" does for it's Set of Strings